# InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a task that has completed

Tags: c#

I have the following function:

```
public static void StartWithErrorLogging(Func<Task> task, IAresLogger logger, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        new Task(async () =>
        {
            try
            {

                await task.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger?.Log(LogMessageSeverity.Error, e.Message, e);
            }
        }, token).Start();
    }
```

Which is called by using the following code:

```
     ErrorLoggedTask.StartWithErrorLogging(async () => await _recentSearchRepository.InsertAsync(new RecentSearch
            {
                AuthUserId = user.Subject.UserAuthId,
                SearchDate = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                SearchText = filter.SearchTerm
            }, token), _logger, token);
```

Sometime it raises the following exception:

> {
>       "exception" : "System.InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on 
>       a task that has completed.\r\n   at
>       System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Start(TaskScheduler scheduler)\r\n   at
>       Ares.Core.Scheduling.ErrorLoggedTask.StartWithErrorLogging(Func`1 task, 
>       IAresLogger logger, CancellationToken token) in
>       C:\..\ErrorLoggedTask.cs:line 15\r\n   at
>       Ares.Api.Controllers.SearchController.d__17.MoveNext() in
>       C:\...\SearchController.cs:line 97\r\n--- End of 
>       stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>       System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at
>
> InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a task that has completed

What I can do in that?

Comment: `new Task` is wrong. Use `Task.Run` instead of the `Task` constructor

Comment: try adding `Task.Delay(5000);
`

Comment: has the parameter `task` already completed?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why in the world would you use `Task.Run` here?  There's no synchronous method that needs to be run in a thread pool thread.

Comment: @Servy Plain simple: the `Task` constructor should be avoided unless you know the exact parameters that should be used

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sure, but in this case the solution is to just remove it entirely *and replace it with nothing*, not to replace it with `Task.Run`.  Suggesting that `Task.Run` be used when it isn't a situation where it should be used isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

[You should never use the `Task` constructor.](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html)

A straightforward translation of your code using `Task.Run` instead would look like this:

```
public static void StartWithErrorLogging(Func<Task> task, IAresLogger logger)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {

            await task.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger?.Log(LogMessageSeverity.Error, e.Message, e);
        }
    });
}
```

(I removed the `CancellationToken`, since [it most likely wasn't doing anything useful anyway](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html)). In fact, the code you posted only causes that exception if the `CancellationToken` is cancelled before `Start` is called.

However, you almost certainly shouldn't use this code, because it is [fire-and-forget on the threadpool, which is an antipattern on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Comment: You should not be posting an answer to say that the question doesn't contain enough information to reproduce the problem.  Answers are there to answer the question, not to request clarification from the question author.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN "That said, the code you posted should never have caused the exception you posted. I recommend looking through the rest of your codebase and removing every instance of the Task constructor."  The answer *specifically* says that the question doesn't contain enough information to be answered.  Everything else in the answer has nothing to do with what the question is asking about.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN The *rest* of the answer is a side note.  None of the rest of the answer has anything to do with what the question is asking, nor does it even attempt to answer it (we know as much because the answer *says* that it's not possible to answer the question, so they haven't tried).  If you think that this is answering the question, then according to you, how is Stephen proposing that the OP do to prevent them from getting the error that they're getting (which is after all what the question is asking)?

Comment: @Servy I believe that changing the code per this answer will avoid the exception posted because the exception specifically calls out the `Start` call in `StartWithErrorLogging`, and that has been eliminated.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Then you disagree with Stephen who *specifically* says in this answer that the change specified doesn't fix that problem.  The code removed *doesn't* call `Start` on a promise style task, it calls it on a task provided by the `Task` constructor, for which calling `Start` is valid.  You can of course run the code to see this for yourself, if you don't believe Stephen (or me).

Comment: @Servy: My answer provided three separate useful pieces of knowledge that the op needs to learn. and explained that they likely posted the wrong code. If they follow the guidelines provided in my answer, they'll be able to fix the code that *is* broken. In spite of your constant downvoting, I'm being far more helpful to the op than you.

Comment: @Servy Technically, he didn't say that it didn't fix the problem. He said that the code shouldn't have caused it. But yes. I disagree that the code shown doesn't exhibit part of that problem. The exception makes it pretty obvious that it's a critical piece of the problem if not the whole thing. Maybe the point was that there's more to the problem, but this change is a good start at addressing it?

Comment: @StephenCleary If you want to provide some information that you think is useful, but that isn't an attempt to answer the question, or to say that they posted the wrong code and that they need to improve their question, then that's great, but that information should be posted as a comment, not as an answer, because it's not an answer to the question (as you say so yourself, in  your answer).  If you want to be helpful, then use the right tools for the right job.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN The answer says that the problem is unrelated to the code shown, so the changes to the code shown won't fix the problem.  That you don't understand why the code shown doesn't reproduce the problem can be easily solved by simply *trying out the code for yourself* and seeing if it does in fact reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Answers aren't where you post comments that don't fit into a comment.  That you want to post a comment that's long doesn't make it okay to post it as an answer.  Answers need to attempt to answer the question, not say that the question doesn't have enough information to reproduce the problem, or to suggest changes that don't have anything to do with the problem being asked about.

Comment: @Servy IMO, this answer was helpful enough to be considered and posted as an answer. It's an answer with a caveat that more work is required, which I think is better than no answer in this case, and better than a comment, because it could lead to a final solution. Ideally the answer would be updated if and when more information becomes available, but appears useful as it stands.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN No, it's *not* an answer.  It's a statement that the question *can't* be answered because it does not contain enough information, and some other information not related to the problem that would be a good idea to change.  There is nothing here that "leads to a solution", merely a statement that the question cannot be answered until it is improved.  Saying you think the answer is useful when you don't even understand what the question is asking, or why the question doesn't even contain a reproducible example doesn't mean a whole lot.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Eliminating this call to `Start` *doesn't fix the problem* because this call to `Start` *isn't causing any problems*.  Thus the post *isn't trying to provide an answer to the question*.  If Stephen thought that this call to `Start` was causing this problem then it would be an incorrect answer, but he says, right in the answer, that it's not, so he *knows* that it's not an answer to the question.  You have of course been told this like 5 times now.  You *know* that this call to `Start` isn't causing this problem, so why are you continuing to assert that it is?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN No, *you* are misunderstanding the comment.  Like I've said several times now.  The code provided in the question doesn't reproduce the problem.  You don't need to take my word for it.  *Run the code yourself and see what happens*.  If you get the error the OP is seeing then you know I'm wrong, and your interpretation is correct.  If you *don't* get that error then you'll see that the question doesn't contain enough information to provide an answer, because it doesn't provide a reproducible example.  You can even change the code to Stephen's code to see that nothing changes.